# Eclipse tool can have Plist file?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android development.  Is there any `plist file` editor in Eclipse for Android applications?

Comment: `plist` sound so `iOSish`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you mean a configuration file similar to a plist? Or do you want to read an actual plist in Android?

Comment: i have stored some values in plist in iphone, so now iam working in android application similarly, android have plist file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Adnroid preferences are stored using the android.preference package. These links should help you get started

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

They are built on top of XML files. Android makes use of XML a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no default plist file system (not sure if there are libraries for that) in android except for xml resources. What i used to do is look for a plist to json coverter and use json instead for android.