# Edit plist file as XML in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, plist

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541151/eclipse-tool-can-have-plist-file), but it appears to be Android-specific. How do I get Eclipse to treat `.plist` files as XML? By default, it just opens it in Xcode on my Mac. I can open it in Eclipse with "Open with > Text Editor", but then I don't get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open preferences and go to "General > Editors > File Associations".
2. Next to "File types", click "Add..." and enter `*.plist` as the file type.
3. Next to "Associated editors", click "Add..." and select the XML Editor.
4. Press "OK" a couple of times to get out of preferences.
5. Right click on your plist file and choose "Open with > XML Editor."
6. You may have to restart Eclipse to get syntax highlighting.